# Replace NaN value in one column after applying groupby in another column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, group-by

I want to change the NaN value in Age column by some random variable witin a range by checking the condition in another column.

```
Age     Title
34.5        Mr
47.0        Mrs
62.0        Mr
27.0        Mr
22.0        Mrs
14.0        Mr
30.0        Miss
26.0        Mr
18.0        Mrs
21.0        Mr
NaN     Mr
46.0        Mr
```

There is a age range based on title. For instance the max age of Mrs grp is 76 and Mr is 67. So I want to replace the NaN in Age bsaed on the title. There are 9 title group in total.

I tried

`titanic_df2.loc[(titanic_df2.Title =='Mr') & (titanic_df2['Age'].isnull()), 'Age'] = 14`

But it didn't work.

My dataframe:

```
    PassengerId Survived    Pclass  Sex Age SibSp   Parch   Ticket  Fare    Embarked    Title
0   892 0   3   male    34.5    0   0   330911  7.8292  Q   Mr
1   893 1   3   female  47.0    1   0   363272  7.0000  S   Mrs
2   894 0   2   male    62.0    0   0   240276  9.6875  Q   Mr
3   895 0   3   male    27.0    0   0   315154  8.6625  S   Mr
4   896 1   3   female  22.0    1   1   3101298 12.2875 S   Mrs
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
413 1305    0   3   male    NaN 0   0   A.5. 3236   8.0500  S   Mr
414 1306    1   1   female  39.0    0   0   PC 17758    108.9000    C   Dona
415 1307    0   3   male    38.5    0   0   SOTON/O.Q. 3101262  7.2500  S   Mr
416 1308    0   3   male    NaN 0   0   359309  8.0500  S   Mr
417 1309    0   3   male    5.0 1   1   2668    22.3583 C   Master
```

I tried

```
g = titanic_df2.groupby('Title', group_keys=False)
titanic_df2.loc[(g & (titanic_df2['Age'].isnull())), 'Age'] = random.randint(g.min(),g.max())
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was wrong. Your problem is in conditioning itself. Probably in titanic_df2['Age'].isnull() not giving True where it should be

Comment: Have you considered `np.select`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#flexible-apply) function.

Get the NaNs in the group and replace them by a [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html) of the non NaN values:

```
def fill_random(s):
    m = s.isna()
    return s.mask(m, s[~m].sample(n=m.sum(), replace=True).to_numpy())

df['Age'] = df.groupby('Title', group_keys=False)['Age'].apply(fill_random)
```

Example output:

```
     Age Title
0   34.5    Mr
1   47.0   Mrs
2   62.0    Mr
3   27.0    Mr
4   22.0   Mrs
5   14.0    Mr
6   30.0  Miss
7   26.0    Mr
8   18.0   Mrs
9   21.0    Mr
10  14.0    Mr
11  46.0    Mr
```

Or use a random range (for example with [`numpy.random.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html)) based on the [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.min.html)/[`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html) of the group (note that the min/max are not always the best descriptors of the population):

```
def fill_random_range(s):
    m = s.isna()
    return s.mask(m, np.random.uniform(s.min(), s.max(), size=m.sum()).round(1))

df['Age'] = df.groupby('Title', group_keys=False)['Age'].apply(fill_random_range)
```

Alternatively:

```
g = df.groupby('Title', group_keys=False)['Age']
m = df['Age'].isna()
df.loc[m, 'Age'] = np.random.uniform(g.transform('min')[m],
                                     g.transform('max')[m])
```

Example output:

```
     Age Title
0   34.5    Mr
1   47.0   Mrs
2   62.0    Mr
3   27.0    Mr
4   22.0   Mrs
5   14.0    Mr
6   30.0  Miss
7   26.0    Mr
8   18.0   Mrs
9   21.0    Mr
10  25.6    Mr
11  46.0    Mr
```

Comment: It shows Range exceeds valid bounds error

Comment: @NasimAlGoniShourav can you provide a reproducible input that triggers this error?

Comment: OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16940\1882139340.py in <module>
----> 1 titanic_df2.loc[m, 'Age'] = np.random.uniform(g.transform('min')[m],
      2                                      g.transform('max')[m])

mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.uniform()

OverflowError: Range exceeds valid bounds

Comment: That's the traceback, can your provide a **DataFrame** that gives this error?

Comment: This is my dataframe.

 PassengerId Survived Pclass Sex Age SibSp Parch Ticket Fare Embarked Title
0 892 0 3 male 34.5 0 0 330911 7.8292 Q Mr
1 893 1 3 female 47.0 1 0 363272 7.0000 S Mrs
2 894 0 2 male 62.0 0 0 240276 9.6875 Q Mr
3 895 0 3 male 27.0 0 0 315154 8.6625 S Mr
4 896 1 3 female 22.0 1 1 3101298 12.2875 S Mrs

Comment: Can you edit your question? Comments are not good for data

Comment: I edit my question. Would appreciate some guidance